# What is the definitive way of wrapping sol in anchor?

Tags: anchor

I would like to handle all the wrapping and transferring of sol in the anchor instruction. not in the frontend, but I cant seem to find any examples of how I wrap sol in an instruction on-chain.

If i just want to complete the below code, where i initialize a wSOL ata for the user, what instruction do I put in to wrap SOL to it?

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

use anchor_spl::{
    associated_token::AssociatedToken,
    token::{self, Mint, MintTo, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer},
  };

declare_id!("FiKH951Dj72iSfBq5RmAf5wtvcWAnyxwmBRxaiwVUEgz");

#[program]
pub mod send_spl {
    use super::*;

    pub fn wrap_sol(ctx: Context<WrapSol>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        //wrap sol to wsol account
    

    Ok(())
        
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct WrapSol<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user_sol_account: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = user_sol_account,
        associated_token::mint = wsol_mint,
        associated_token::authority = user_sol_account)]
    pub user_wsol_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub wsol_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

turns out all you have to do is transfer SOL to the token account and sync it

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::system_program;
use anchor_spl::{
    associated_token::AssociatedToken,
    token::{self, Mint, MintTo, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer},
  };

declare_id!("FiKH951Dj72iSfBq5RmAf5wtvcWAnyxwmBRxaiwVUEgz");

#[program]
pub mod send_spl {
    use super::*;
    pub fn wrap_sol(ctx: Context<WrapSol>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
        
        // transfer sol to token account
        let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
        ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        system_program::Transfer {
            from: ctx.accounts.user_sol_account.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.user_wsol_account.to_account_info(),
        });
        system_program::transfer(cpi_context, amount)?;

        // Sync the native token to reflect the new SOL balance as wSOL
        let cpi_accounts = token::SyncNative {
            account: ctx.accounts.user_wsol_account.to_account_info(),
        };
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
        token::sync_native(cpi_ctx)?;

    Ok(())  
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct WrapSol<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user_sol_account: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = user_sol_account,
        associated_token::mint = wsol_mint,
        associated_token::authority = user_sol_account)]
    pub user_wsol_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub wsol_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
}
```